# What order do Japanese people say/recite the seasons?

Tags: set-phrases

In English, I always say winter, spring, summer, fall/autumn, in that order.

Is there a similar order that the Japanese people follow?

Comment: Really? As a UK native I always start with spring. Are you sure your ordering has nothing to do with this song: https://www.songfacts.com/lyrics/carole-king/youve-got-a-friend which forces your order for the purpose of making it rhyme?

Comment: @user3856370: FWIW, as a native speaker of east-coast US English, I also naturally order the seasons as _"winter, spring, summer, fall"_.  My sense is that I learned this order in the order of the seasons starting from the beginning of the calendar year in January, leaving out the duplicated _"winter"_ when getting to November / December (with winter weather usually starting in either month, depending on the year and the location).

Comment: I'd naturally start with "Spring". I don't think that there is a particular order is highly idiomatic.

Comment: As another UK native I also start with spring, but I don't think I've ever seen any American start anywhere other than spring either.

Comment: I did a quick straw poll of the people sitting in my aisle (US Midwest) and got two springs and a winter start. I don't even think this is a regional thing.

Answer (score 6):

In Japan, we say spring, summer, fall, winter.
[春夏秋冬]{しゅん・か・しゅう・とう}

Comment: same in english

Comment: 雨季は欠けているねー。日本がこいしい。。。

Answer (score 1):

We say spring, summer, autumn, winter as both school year and fiscal year start in April.

Most of Japanese people have an image of spring being timing of start. Hundreds of years ago, people called January to March as spring because it was the begining of the year.